# Java: How to have two or more inputs in one line in the console

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am new to java and I wrote a Basic Input/Output program and in this program I want the user to provide 3 different inputs and be saved in 3 different variables, they are two int and one char.

```
public static void ForTesting() {
    Scanner newScanTest = new Scanner(System.in);
    ٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍSystem.out.print("Please type two numbers: ");
    int numberOne = newScanTest.nextInt();
    int numberTwo = newScanTest.nextInt();
    System.out.println("First Nr.: " + numberOne + " Second Nr.: " + numberTwo);
}
```

In the consol

What I get:

Please type two number:  **4**

5

First Nr.: 4 Second Nr.: 5

---

What I want:

Please type two number: **4 5**

First Nr.: 4 Second Nr.: 5

(The bold numbers are the user input)

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, the code should already work? Just don't `enter` after entering a number but type the two numbers separated by a space and then `enter`. Or do you want to *force* the user to enter one line only?

Comment: I think this worked, so the user does not have to press enter to show that he has typed the first input?

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`nextLine()`, as the name suggests, reads a single line. If both numbers are contained on this single line, you should read both integers from that line. For example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scanner.nextLine();  // reads the single input line from the console
String[] strings = line.split(" ");  // splits the string wherever a space character is encountered, returns the result as a String[]
int first = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
int second = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
System.out.println("First number = " + first + ", second number = " + second + ".");
```

Note, this will fail if you don't provide 2 integers in the input.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Would this also work if I also want a char in the middle for example the user input is  2 + 2, and that all three inputs on one line.

I will try your way and get back to you.
thanks

Comment: If you know exactly what characters will be in between the 2 numbers, you pass it as an argument to `line.split()`. If the input is "2 + 2", then the function should be `line.split(" + ");`. The spaces on either side are important.

Comment: @cameron1024 Which version of Java you are using? Do Scanner class have readLine() method?

Comment: No, I don't know what char it will be, the user needs to input three thing --> first int then a char and then second int --> firstInt(3) then char(+ or - or * or /) then secondInt(4)

Comment: My mistake, it is `nextLine()` not `readLine()`, ill edit my answer

Comment: @psi I am new to Java and I really don't know.

Comment: @MK Berou I think you can try approach suggested by cameron1024 but i suspects even nextLine() will not work.

Comment: @MK Berou I have posted my answer below... you can take look at it as alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bellow code, i try to convert integers to strings.

```
public static void ForTesting() {
    Scanner newScanTest = new Scanner(System.in);
    ٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍٍSystem.out.print("Please type two numbers: ");
    int number = newScanTest.nextInt();
    int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(number).substring(0, 1));
    int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(number).substring(1, 2));
    System.out.println("First Nr.: " + firstDigit + " Second Nr.: " + secondDigit);
}
```

Comment: Okay will try it and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure about input like (2+2) or (2-2) or (2*2) or (2/2)
below should work -

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer first = scanner.nextInt();
String operator = scanner.next();
Integer second = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("First number = " + first + ", second number = " + second + ".");
```